# Cannot find module '@angular/forms' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: angular

I just ran an 'npm update' on my project and some errors occured by the 'import' parts of some ts components like this (and of course tons of compilation errors):

[image]

What should I do now? How can I modify the code, or turn it back to work the imports again?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: does `node_modules/@angular/forms` exist?

Comment: Did you type ng serve? It can be this because new Angular versions compile some packages to es2015

Comment: @ Get Off My Lawn: that was the first what I checked: and every underlined folders exist in the destiantion folders...

Comment: I have done a full restart and the errors passed away but I have a compilation error message: "Error: Angular structure loaded both synchronously and asynchronously"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By stopping 'ng serve' and start it again solved the problem.